# Tackle for catching bass on live bait

Tags: fishing, fishing-tackle, bait

What tackle do I need for catching bass on live bait in fresh water?

Fish: Largemouth bass, Northern pike and Smallmouth bass

Mean depth of lake is 8ft.

Comment: Worms, bass love worms.

Answer (score 2):

Rod, reel (with line), hooks, sinkers, and probably bobbers. Landing net is optional.

Comment: you can also "float" worms a foot or two off the bottom of the lake, by injecting air into the worm and/or putting a very small float at the end of the line, near the hook, and a somewhat larger weight a foot or two above the float, so that the weight stays on the lake floor and the worm floats above it.

Comment: What do you use when inflating worms?

Answer (score 1):

I honestly can't say for certain until I actually fish at a place, but off the top of my head I'd say:

- 8ft+ rod if your'e fishing from the shore, and 6ft rod if your'e on a boat.
- Mono-filament 10 to 20lb test line.
- Circle hooks.
- Net
- Bait cooler with an aerator
- 2 to 3oz weights
- A bell and glow sticks for the evening and early morning
- Pile worms
- Mud suckers
- If you have time to fish for your bait, bluegills and squaw fish are great.
- Night-crawlers for bluegills, Powerbait for squaw fish.